# Is there a way to check when a set mediaelement position is reached?

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

When I set the position in a mediaelement is there any event or thing to check to see when it has reached that position?
I have tried to check for buffering as I figured it would do that but no. I have also tried get the position but that one of cause returns what I just set even though the seek is not yet done.

Answer (score 0):

You can check (MediaElement.Position Property) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.position.aspx

Comment: That one does not work for me as I said because when I set the position it will immediatly return that value even though it have not finished seeking to that point.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no event to support that. If your aim is to play the file from x position to y position, you can use MediaTimeline, create a clock from it and add the clock to MediaElement. If however, you need to synchronise something with your playback, the only option is to use a timer to check for position again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
private async void videoElement_SeekCompleted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

That seems to fire once the position has changed, and the video has been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

For those that came looking for `MediaPlayerElement` instead of MediaElement (as Microsoft's docs recommend using), you can do this by subscribing to:

```
someMediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PositionChanged;
```

Then, in the handler, check `sender.Position` for the new position.